# Function only showing broken image links to the browser

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JS and was trying to build a function that would choose a random picture from an array and display it on the browser. The function seems to be working, however it only shows broken link images. This is the code i've written so far.

```
let misImagenes = ['img/boski.jpg', 'img/carlanga.jpg','img/donny.jpg','img/gato.jpg',
'img/lococharcas.jpg','img/monsi.jpg']; 

function randomImg(){
    let image = document.createElement('img');
    let div = document.getElementById('ruleta');
    image.src = 'misImagenes';
    div.appendChild(image);
    Math.floor(Math.random() * misImagenes);

}
```

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Quien tiene que bajar?</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
      <div id="logo">
        <div>
        <h1>Alguien tiene que bajar.</h1>
        <p> <b>A los pibes les encanta tomas sus tragos fríos <br>
        pero núnca quieren buscar el hielo.</b></p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div>
        <div class="cuerpo">
            <h2>Que la suerte decida quien busca el hielo</h2>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="randomImg()">Suerte ñeri</button>
            <p>presiona</p>
            <div id="ruleta">
              
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <h2>Powered by Donny</h2>
    </footer>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```
Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Big rookie here.
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
function randomImg() {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * misImagenes.length;
  let image = document.createElement('img');
  let div = document.getElementById('ruleta');
  image.src = misImagenes[randomIndex];
  div.appendChild(image);
}
```